# One in a million: a musical charm

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language

Here's a simple riddle I came up with myself. If this puzzle already exists elsewhere on the Web, please forgive me, I didn't know about it.

> As a whole, I'm charmed. Remove two letters from the start and end, I make music. Remove one more letter from the end of the previous result, and I'm afraid I'm unable. Remove *three* letters from the start and end, and I'm one in a million. What am I?

The answer is one word, and yes, it's a *real word*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As a whole, I'm charmed.

> *encantado*, "charmed" in Spanish

> Remove two letters from the start and end, I make music.

> *canta*, "music" in Spanish

> Remove one more letter from the end of the previous result, and I'm afraid I'm unable.

> *can't*

> Remove three letters from the start and end, and I'm one in a million.

> *ant*, which tends to teem in large numbers

Comment: All correct, except that _canta_ means "sing". Well done!